# How to make animation using ObjectAnimator?

Tags: android, kotlin, objectanimator

My application is used in landscape orientation. What I want to do is move an element from off the screen at all until it enters the screen and then when pressing a button, it leaves the screen again by scrolling to the left.[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a **TranslationX** animation, see below, or check out this link. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view

```
ObjectAnimator translateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", deltaX);
ObjectAnimator translateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", deltaY);
```

If you have any question, please feel free.:)

Comment: Always I use translationX, the animation starts in the left of the screen to the value I define. How can I define where the animation start? Start at the right of the screen and then, apply the animation

Comment: View.post{animate by x using view.getx()}

Answer (score 0):

The animation starts from the default position of the view (i.e the position you have specified in your xml file). if you do not what the animation to start from that position, you can either:

1. change the initial position of the view in the xml file.
2. or set the x and y coordinates of the view at run time and then start your animation like so:

```
ObjectAnimator translateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", deltaX);
```